# График двух рядов разного размера

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как нарисовать на одном графике одновременно 2 ряда разного размера: в одном  полный набор значений (например, 100), а в другом значения должны отображаться в 10 раз реже (всего 10 значений).

Есть пример подобного графика:

[image: Пример такого графика]

Значения рядов лежат в списках, там пусть и хранятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятна ваша проблема. В `plt.plot` вы указываете `x` и `y` для первого и второго рядов, поэтому не важно какой ряд больше, какой меньше.

Вот простой пример:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.random_sample(len(x))
x1 = x[::10]
y1 = np.random.random_sample(len(x1)) / 2

plt.figure()

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x1, y1, '+')

plt.show()
```

Если же вам нужно прорядить ряд и взять каждое 10 значение, то можно воспользоваться обычным срезом: `y[::10]`.

Comment: `plt.figure()` не надо.

Comment: Не обязательно, но полезно, так как передавая параметры в `figure`, вы можете настроить название окна, размеры и т.п.

Comment: ... что вы всё равно не делаете :-)

Comment: В данном случае вроде и не нужно. Но уже выработалась привычка таким образом оформлять код)